# Python+ Cplex error : No module named 'docplex'

Tags: python, spyder, cplex

I have the following error once I run the code in Spyder, any suggestions??

from docplex.mp.model import Model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docplex'

I installed Cplex recently

Comment: pip install, read the doc

Comment: Thank you, I have tried "!pip install cplex " in spyder but didn't work
What doc??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun 21 21:45:04 2022

@author: n99432
"""
#%%
from docplex.mp.model import Model
## Sets
F = [1,2] # Farmers


runcell(2, 'C:/Users/N99432/OneDrive -XXXXXXXa/untitled2.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\N99432\OneDrive - XXXXXXXa\untitled2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from docplex.mp.model import Model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docplex'

Comment: Maybe you are using the Spyder standalone version? If that is the case, you will need to create an enviroment to use custom packages outside the ones that come bundled. For more info you can check the Spyder docs FAQ page: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Answer (score 2):

As can be read at http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/getting_started_python.html

you should use

```
pip install docplex
```